# Preposition to use with "concordance"

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

Do you say *concordance of A and B*, *concordance of A with B*, *concordance between A and B*, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this Google NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=concordance+with%2C+concordance+of%2C+concordance+between&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), all of them are used but *concordance of* is most common:

[image]

However, this provided me with an originally false conclusion: the uses of *concordance of* refer to the use of *concordance* as an index, rather than "an agreement". Looking into the actual results in Google Books of ["concordance of"](http://www.google.com/search?q=concordance+of&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), the other definition of *concordance* is being used. Thus, in order to express "agreement", use [*concordance between*](http://www.google.com/search?q=concordance+of&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=concordance+between&pbx=1&oq=concordance+between&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=26331l27430l0l27598l7l6l0l0l0l0l330l1372l2-4.1l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=f717a7e5f64986dc&biw=1366&bih=667) as in "there was an agreement between A and B".

Comment: Thanks!! This is great.  I did some google search, and sometimes "concordance of" is used like this: "concordance of Shakespeare's works."  Is there a way to narrow the ngram to only consider sentence structures like "concordance of A and B"?  Maybe I'm using the word incorrectly?

Comment: But many of those instance of *concordance of* probably represent the other meaning, as in *a concordance of Shakespeare*, *Strong’s Exhaustive Concordance of the Bible*, etc. I suspect that *concordance between* is the most common form in the sense ‘agreement’.

Comment: @Neil: I'm not sure if you can search NGrams that specifically, but you can go into the Google Books and search just as you would normally. For example, I searched "concordance of" [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=concordance+of+and&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @Brian Ah, you're very right. Let me do some more research.